# render views's order in react native android and iOS?

Tags: react-native

I have a view in react native witch contains some child views. I need to perform some functions right after each views rendered.
my views are in this order :

Base Parent view  ---> parent view ---> child view

so I need to calculate some layout dimention in parent view but exactly after child view is created.

in Android I dont have any problem
bu in iOS these views created in no order so I cant do my calculation.
How can I be sure to run a function exactly after all childs are created?
this is my base parent view :

```
<View onLayout={this.getGridExactPos} style={{width: '100%' , aspectRatio: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>           
           {this.constructViews()}              
         </View>
```

this is my childs in above container:

```
constructViews = () => {
    let strings = 'a,b,c,d|s,d,f,g|h,b,a,u|m,l,k,o';
    let answers = '01,12,23';
    let arrayST = strings.split("|");
    for(i=0;i<arrayST.length;i++){
        arrayST[i] =  arrayST[i].split(",");
    }
    let rows = [];
    let currentIndex = 0
    let currentRowIndex = 0
    for (let i = 1; i <=arrayST.length; i++) {
      let row = [];          
      for (let j = 1; j <=arrayST.length; j++) {      
        const boxIndex = currentIndex++  
        let stateKey = `${i}${j}`;            
        row.push(
          <View onLayout={ (e) => this.getExactPos(e, stateKey, boxIndex)} style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor : this.state.boxes[boxIndex].bgColor}]} key={stateKey}><Text>{this.state.boxes[boxIndex].title}</Text></View>
        );
      }
      const rowIndex = currentRowIndex++
      rows.push(
        <View onLayout={ (e) => this.fixPos(e, rowIndex)} style={styles.row} key={i}>{row}</View>
      );
    }        
    return rows;
  }
```

so I need to run 'this.fixPos' exactly after 'this.getExactPos' and finally after this loop finished I need to run 'this.getGridExactPos'.

in android I dont have problem but in iOS there is no order so makes me mistake.

thanks for your advices.